# keras load_weights() can not load weights

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to load weights from `.hdf5` file, and use `load_weights()`. 
Error doesn't occur. But when I use the model to predict. The result is the same with the model before I load weights.

The load weights doesn't work.
My `keras` version is 2.2.2
`tensorflow` version is 1.10.0

How can I solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: What is your specific error message? How do you store the model? Please post the corresponding code.

Answer (score 3):

Have you saved weight and load weight like this?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Compile model

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fit the model & evaluate

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

serialize model to JSON

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

serialize weights to HDF5

```
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

later...
load json and create model

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

load weights into new model

```
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

evaluate loaded model on test data

```
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

Comment: what is the class/function i should import for save and load weights?

Comment: from keras.models import model_from_json

Comment: Actually, I use checkpoint to save my model's weights in the another computer and download the hdf5 file, then I am trying to load the weights from this hdf5 file. I did not save the json file.  Is this why this problem happened?   However, I use load_weights('***.hdf5') on the original computer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share code on how you are saving model in.hd5 then we would be able to assist you. Assuming you are trying to solve a "Computer Vision" problem. Also if needed you can print shape after input and pooling layer
It is best practice to save weights instead of whole model as mentioned in Keras docs. Hope this helps

For eg: I have used modelcheckpoint to load a model (or feature extractor model). Also note below code is in [functional API](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/).

```
# create a base model(eg: EfficientNetB0 and so on)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
# include_top=False allow setting base model per your problem

# freeze layer
base_model.trainable=False

# create inputs
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224,224,3), name="input_layer")

# pass inputs to base model
x = base_model(inputs)

# perform pooling
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="pooling_layer")(x)


# create outputs
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax",name="output_layer")(x)
# need to modify classes per your problem

# combine inputs and outputs with base model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs)

# compile model
.... 


#fit model
model.fit(train_data, epochs=5,validation_data=test_data,validation_steps=len(test_data),callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(ckhpt_filepath,save_weights=True,save_best_only=True,save_freq="epoch",verbose=1)

# load best weights and evaluate model
model.load_weights(ckhpt_filepath)
loaded_model_results = model.evaluate(test_data)
```